# I am getting this error- "exceptions.ArrowErrorException: This app has encountered an error." on streamlit web app when deployed on cloud

Tags: python, parquet, streamlit, python-polars

I am new to **Streamlit** and this my first app that I have uploaded on the **streamlit cloud**.

**App**: https://india-bse-stocks.streamlit.app/One_stock_analysis

**github repo**: https://github.com/johnsnow09/streamlit_bse_101/tree/master

I am using **parquet file** (more than 300 mb size) and **polars** scan_parquet() to read the parquet file. The app works perfectly fine on my local machine but I am getting an error when deployed and not sure what's wrong.

**Some logs below:**

```
Updated app!

2023-03-15 12:53:39.519 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 31, in <module>

    df = get_data()

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 23, in get_data

    df = pl.scan_parquet('./df_bse_compiled_3.parquet')

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper

    return function(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/io.py", line 704, in scan_parquet

    return LazyFrame._scan_parquet(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 234, in _scan_parquet

    self._ldf = PyLazyFrame.new_from_parquet(

exceptions.ArrowErrorException: ExternalFormat("File out of specification: The file must end with PAR1")

2023-03-15 12:53:45.738 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/3_Industry_analysis.py", line 30, in <module>

    df = get_data()

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/3_Industry_analysis.py", line 23, in get_data

    df = pl.scan_parquet('V:/1. R & Python work/Python/2.AnalytixLabs Practice/Streamlit 101/df_bse_compiled_3.parquet')

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper

    return function(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/io.py", line 704, in scan_parquet

    return LazyFrame._scan_parquet(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 226, in _scan_parquet

    scan = pli._scan_parquet_fsspec(file, storage_options)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/anonymous_scan.py", line 148, in _scan_parquet_fsspec

    schema = pli.read_parquet_schema(data)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/io.py", line 234, in read_parquet_schema

    return _parquet_schema(file)

FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: ...teuqrap.3_delipmoc_esb_fd/101 tilmaertS/ecitcarP sbaLxitylanA.2/nohtyP/krow nohtyP & R .

2023-03-15 12:53:47.764 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 31, in <module>

    df = get_data()

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 23, in get_data

    df = pl.scan_parquet('./df_bse_compiled_3.parquet')

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper

    return function(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/io.py", line 704, in scan_parquet

    return LazyFrame._scan_parquet(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 234, in _scan_parquet

    self._ldf = PyLazyFrame.new_from_parquet(

exceptions.ArrowErrorException: ExternalFormat("File out of specification: The file must end with PAR1")

2023-03-15 12:54:11.886 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/3_Industry_analysis.py", line 30, in <module>

    df = get_data()

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/3_Industry_analysis.py", line 23, in get_data

    df = pl.scan_parquet('V:/1. R & Python work/Python/2.AnalytixLabs Practice/Streamlit 101/df_bse_compiled_3.parquet')

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper

    return function(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/io.py", line 704, in scan_parquet

    return LazyFrame._scan_parquet(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 226, in _scan_parquet

    scan = pli._scan_parquet_fsspec(file, storage_options)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/anonymous_scan.py", line 148, in _scan_parquet_fsspec

    schema = pli.read_parquet_schema(data)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/io.py", line 234, in read_parquet_schema

    return _parquet_schema(file)

FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: ...teuqrap.3_delipmoc_esb_fd/101 tilmaertS/ecitcarP sbaLxitylanA.2/nohtyP/krow nohtyP & R .

2023-03-15 12:56:37.424 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 31, in <module>

    df = get_data()

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 23, in get_data

    df = pl.scan_parquet('./df_bse_compiled_3.parquet')

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper

    return function(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/io.py", line 704, in scan_parquet

    return LazyFrame._scan_parquet(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 234, in _scan_parquet

    self._ldf = PyLazyFrame.new_from_parquet(

exceptions.ArrowErrorException: ExternalFormat("File out of specification: The file must end with PAR1")

2023-03-15 13:02:44.640 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 31, in <module>

    df = get_data()

  File "/app/streamlit_bse_101/pages/2_One_stock_analysis.py", line 23, in get_data

    df = pl.scan_parquet('./df_bse_compiled_3.parquet')

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper

    return function(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/io.py", line 704, in scan_parquet

    return LazyFrame._scan_parquet(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py", line 234, in _scan_parquet

    self._ldf = PyLazyFrame.new_from_parquet(

exceptions.ArrowErrorException: ExternalFormat("File out of specification: The file must end with PAR1")
```

Comment: UPDATE: (1). I have made some code changes and reduced the parquet file to under 1 Mb & it worked - https://johnsnow09-streamlit-bse-301-1-homepage-uqpq09.streamlit.app/ https://github.com/johnsnow09/streamlit_bse_301  

(2) I used above files & combined with 300+ mb parquet file and again started to get the same error as in this post https://johnsnow09-streamlit-bse-401-1-homepage-07jxey.streamlit.app/One_stock_analysis https://github.com/johnsnow09/streamlit_bse_401

Comment: You may have been hitting a resource error if the app was crashing when the file was larger. I'm also seeing a "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: ../df_bse_compiled_3.parquet" error in the logs a while back

Comment: Yes even I thought of the same issue but I wasn't sure. Thanks for replying here @CarolineFrasca .. appreciate that !!!